# How to get a mobile page height without changing the page width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, height

How can I get the page height on mobile without actually being on mobile? Let's say that I want to get the page height when it's 600px wide. The content changes (text wrap, media queries, etc.), so the height is different than on a normal screen.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    let pageHeight = $(document).height();
    console.log("Page height: " pageHeight + "px");
});
```

How to change the script above to simulate the page height as if the width was 600px?
I don't want to change the page width (everything should be calculated without any visible changes to the page). How can I do this?

Comment: A better way might be to use browser dev tools.  See: [Simulate mobile devices with Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/)

Comment: @Yogi I think you misunderstood what I'm trying to achieve. I want to simulate the width of the screen to get the page height as a variable that I can use in my JS code. I don't want to see how my page would look like on mobile.

Comment: If it is always he same content, it could be enough to get the height in the developer tools and define the found value in your js code. Else i don't think that such a programmatical simulation is possible, or easy to build...

Comment: @biberman Unfortunately, that's the case. I wouldn't create a question if the content wouldn't change.

Comment: I guess you could clone the whole content to a new container, with opacity: 0 so you don't see it, which has your fixed width, calculate the height, then remove the div again.  Sounds quite unpleasant, but not sure what else you could do...

Comment: This is starting to sound like a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/320245), i.e., "asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem." So what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  Perhaps there is an alternative, like [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) break points, that would be a better solution.

Comment: @Yogi I think that it's a pretty open question. The problem: I want to know the exact page height as if the screen would be 600px wide (and have it as a variable in JS), but without actually changing the screen width. I need to try out the solution that Paul suggested.

Comment: I tried @PaulCrozer idea: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1oxa76hg/2/).  It loads the page set at 600px width and opacity 0, gets the height, and then fades in the page at the normal width. However, this only works correctly when there are no media queries on the page. The demo page has a 768px break point. And the problem is that break points are triggered by window height and width. So the height will be off when doc width is 600px but the window is >= 768.  In other words, it breaks the normal reflow of the page.  Yet, if your page doesn't use media queries then this might be a solution.

Comment: @Yogi When I have some time I will try it. Won't container queries work? Or I can just set specific styles to the content in a div with class, so normal style ```p{colorLredl}``` and for the 600px container ```.mobile_load p{color:pink}```.

Comment: Your normal css rules and queries will work fine.  Media queries are something different. They are styles that apply css rules only to certain screen sizes. Bootstrap and other libraries often use these to help the page automatically adjust to desktop and mobile.